# Find whole words without regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to find whole words in a sentence, but without using regular expressions.  So if I wanted to find the word "the" in this sentence: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", I'm currently using:

```
 String text = "the, quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
 String keyword = "the";

 Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\b"+keyword+"\\b").matcher(text);
 Boolean contains = matcher.find();
```

but if I used:

```
Boolean contains = text.contains(keyword);
```

and pad the keyword with a space, it won't find the first "the" in the sentence, both because it doesn't have surround whitespaces and the punctuations.

To be clear, I'm building an Android app, and I'm getting memory leaks and it might be because I'm using a regular-expression in a ListView, so it's performing a regular-expression match X number of times, depending on the items in the Listview.

Comment: do you need the spaces for some reason?

Comment: "without using regular expressions". Because an instructor forbade you from doing so? If that's the case, please add the "Homework" tag.

Comment: You can add spaces to the string to search in too.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use regex?

Comment: If this question is a followup to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830128/spannablestring-regex-in-a-listview), please go back and check my answer there.  You *can* use regexes to solve that problem, and it's much easier than what you're trying to do here.

Comment: This is a follow-up to that question, though I must have missed your response.  I'll check it out.  I'm building an Android app, so using regex's are expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int findWholeWorld(final String text, final String searchString) {
    return (" " + text + " ").indexOf(" " + searchString + " ");
}
```

This will give you the index of the first occurrence of the word "the" or -1 if the word "the" doesn't exist.

Comment: My answer wouldn't work in that case.  You would still want to do something like `indexOf` and then check that the letters before and after the string are either the start/end of the string or not characters (or hyphens if you are allowing hyphenated words).

Answer (score 1):

If you needed to check for multiple words and do it **without regular expressions** you could use [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) with a space as the delimiter.

You could then build a custom search method. Otherwise, the other solutions using `String.contains()` or `String.indexOf()` qualify.

Comment: What about punctuations?  Technically, "the, quick brown fox" should bring back true.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is search for `"the"`.  Then for each match you test to see if the surrounding characters are white space (or punctuation), or if the match is at the beginning / end of the string respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on space, and then see if the resulting array contains your word.

Comment: Technically `String.split()` uses a regular expression :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over the characters and keep storing them in a char buffer. Every time you see a whitespace, empty the buffer into a list of words and go on till you reach the end.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments of the StringTokenizer.class:

StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for
compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is
recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split
method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

The following example illustrates how the String.split
method can be used to break up a string into its basic tokens:

```
String[] result = "this is a test".split("\\s");
for (int x=0; x&lt;result.length; x++)
    System.out.println(result[x]);
```

prints the following output:

```
this
is
a
test
```

Iterate through your resulting string array and test for equality and keep a count.

```
for (String s : result)
{
 count++;
}
```

If this is a homework assignment, tell your lecturer to read up on Java, times have changed. I remember having the exact same stupid questions during school and it does nothing to prepare you for the real world.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that requires whole word matching, but I can't use regular expressions(because regular expressions escape some keywords), I tried to write my own code to simulate it with non-regular expressions (`\bxxx\b`), I only know `C#` and it worked fine.

```
public static class Finder
{
    public static bool Find(string? input, string? pattern, bool isMatchCase = false, bool isMatchWholeWord = false, bool isMatchRegex = false)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pattern))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!isMatchCase && !isMatchRegex)
        {
            input = input.ToLower();
            pattern = pattern.ToLower();
        }

        if (isMatchWholeWord && !isMatchRegex)
        {
            int len = pattern.Length;
            int suffix = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                int start = input.IndexOf(pattern, suffix);

                if (start == -1)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                int end = start + len - 1;

                int prefix = start - 1;
                suffix = end + 1;

                bool isPrefixMatched, isSuffixMatched;

                if (start == 0)
                {
                    isPrefixMatched = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isPrefixMatched = IsWord(input[prefix]) != IsWord(input[start]);
                }

                if (end == input.Length - 1)
                {
                    isSuffixMatched = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isSuffixMatched = IsWord(input[suffix]) != IsWord(input[end]);
                }

                if (isPrefixMatched && isSuffixMatched)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isMatchRegex)
        {
            if (isMatchWholeWord)
            {
                if (!pattern.StartsWith(@"\b"))
                {
                    pattern = $@"\b{pattern}";
                }

                if (!pattern.EndsWith(@"\b"))
                {
                    pattern = $@"{pattern}\b";
                }
            }

            return Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern, isMatchCase ? RegexOptions.None : RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }

        return input.Contains(pattern);
    }

    private static bool IsWord(char ch)
    {
        return Char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) || ch == '_';
    }
}
```