# How to color text using Regex in android

Tags: java, android, regex

I have three regular expression:

```
Pattern mentionPattern = Pattern.compile("(@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
Pattern hashtagPattern = Pattern.compile("(#[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
Pattern urlPattern = Patterns.WEB_URL;
```

I have a string :

This is a **#sample**  **#twitter** text of **@tom_cruise** with a link **http://tom_cruise.me**

I need to match this text with the above three regular expression and color the matched text with Blue and set the final text in a `TextView`. How can I achieve that?

It is to be mentioned that I don't need to `Linkify` the text, only coloring. And I am not using `Twitter4j` Library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I replaced `http://tom_cruise.me` with `http://www.google.com`. Try the following:

```
String a = "This is a #sample #twitter text of @tom_cruise with a link http://www.google.com";

Pattern mentionPattern = Pattern.compile("(@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
Pattern hashtagPattern = Pattern.compile("(#[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
Pattern urlPattern = Patterns.WEB_URL;

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(a.length());
Matcher o = hashtagPattern.matcher(a);

while (o.find()) {
    o.appendReplacement(sb, "<font color=\"#437C17\">" + o.group(1) + "</font>");
}
o.appendTail(sb);

Matcher n = mentionPattern.matcher(sb.toString());
sb = new StringBuffer(sb.length());

while (n.find()) {
    n.appendReplacement(sb, "<font color=\"#657383\">" + n.group(1) + "</font>");
}
n.appendTail(sb);

Matcher m = urlPattern.matcher(sb.toString());
sb = new StringBuffer(sb.length());

while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "<font color=\"#EDDA74\">" + m.group(1) + "</font>");
}
m.appendTail(sb);

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :) Everything seems okay except two things. How can I put color code instead of blue? I tried it but not working. And the '@' and '#' are not showing in the final text

Comment: @typedef The required portions of the text aren't blue? Or are you saying that you are not able to use a different color code.

Comment: I need a different color code close to blue like `#6ccff6` but after applying `<font color=\"#6ccff6\">` The color isn't change. Instead it is showing the markup in textview

Comment: @typedef No, the codes aren't working as expected. Let me try and figure out a workaround.

Comment: Please edit your answer because my regular expression was little bit buggy. it should be `(@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)` instead of `@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)` and `(#[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)` instead of `#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)` and then no need to prepend `@` and `#` first. Please let me know if you can fix the color code issue

Comment: Also `<font color='#145A14'>` solve my problem. Please edit your answer with this. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @typedef I have edited my answer above after solving the color code problem in a hackish way. What we are doing here is passing the `StringBuffer` from one `Matcher` to the next. So, the `Matcher` with `(#[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)` is messing up with color codes. In my edited code above, I am passing the original string to `Pattern hashtagPattern` first. And then, whatever comes out is passed to the other matchers. This solves your color code problem. And, thanks for the accept!

Comment: Now your code is perfectly working! Thanks a lot! You've saved my day!

Comment: Great code, also check this for making clickable with SpannableString http://stackoverflow.com/a/7837610/3736955

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`SpannableString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) and [`SpannableStringBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html). An example of using the `SpannableStringBuilder` is available at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16061128/1321873

You could write a method that accepts the non-styled `String` and returns a `CharSequence` like so:

```
private CharSequence getStyledTweet(String tweet){
    SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(tweet);
    //Find the indices of the hashtag pattern, mention pattern and url patterns 
    //and set the spans accordingly
    //...
    return stringBuilder;
}
```

and then use the return value from the above to set the text of the `TextView`

```
TextView tView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
tView.setText(getStyledTweet(tweet));
```