# Highlight a particular word in a String dynamically

Tags: android

> I want to highlight a particular word in a text view ( more specifically similar to a twitter feed). The word may occur multiple times. Below I will post a  sample sentence from twitter.

" ***Mumbai Master Blaster! #Sachin. Greatest players of all times. The legend of cricket  #sachin.*** "

Here I want to highlight the word " #Sachin " with a particular color. Also please note that we don't know how many times this word could get repeated in the whole string. Could anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android

Comment: you should try out the api demos which are available via the sdk manager. they have a nice example there.

Comment: Exactly what you want: [How to color text using Regex in android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17848858/2558882).

Answer (score 0):

Use next code:

```
public CharSequence linkifyHashtags(String text) {
    SpannableStringBuilder linkifiedText = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@\\w");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int start = matcher.start();
        int end = matcher.end();
        String hashtag = text.substring(start, end);
        ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);
        linkifiedText.setSpan(span, 0, hashtag.length(), 0);
    }
    return linkifiedText;
}
```

Comment: @user2558882 : thanks..It is a useful link. I tried it out and  worked for me.